# The timer ref is canceled or not when a process die?

Tags: erlang

I spawn a process, and run `timer:apply_interval` in the spawned process, but the timer ref seem is invalid.

Here is the code:

```
2> {ok, File} = file:open("plcLog.txt", [append, raw]).
{ok,{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.536>,10}}}
3>  spawn(fun() -> {ok, Tref} = timer:apply_interval(1, file, write, [File, "hello world"])
end).  
<0.37.0>
4> 
4> file:close(File).
ok
```

When i check the content of `"plcLog.txt"`, it is empty.

So i think the timer ref is invalid after the spwan process die.
Is it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document of Timer mentioned  timer created by evaluating any of the functions apply_interval/4 is linked to the process towards which the timer performs its task. Pay attention the WARNING section of [Man page of Timer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html)